# Arxiv conflict with submitted papers

Tags: publications, arxiv, online-publication, preprint

I have submitted my paper to Proceedings of the AMS one month ago and we haven't gotten a response yet. Can I upload my paper to arxiv despite of this? Would there be any conflict? About accepted ones, they have written that there is no conflict and so: Can I deduce from this that there wouldn't be any conflict for submitted ones as well?

Thanks

Comment: UPDATE: since 2022, Proceedings of the AMS has a double-blind review model, which means authors should endeavor to keep their connection to the paper secret. Please read the submission guidelines carefully before uploading to arXiv if you plan to publish in Proceedings of the AMS: https://www.ams.org/news?news_id=6983

Answer (score 15):

Yes, in mathematics you can absolutely upload both submitted and accepted papers.  I am not aware of a single reputable mathematics journal that would take issue with this.  (If it helps, within the last few months I uploaded a paper to the arxiv after I submitted it but before acceptance.)  What I do not recommend is to upload to the arxiv papers which have been formatted in the journal's style file or which incorporate copyediting done after acceptance by the staff of the journal.

If a journal is published by a big academic publisher and you are the kind of person to worry about this at all (honestly I didn't, for many years), you should be able to find online a relevant policy for uploading preprints.  In all of my experience, even big publishers like Elsevier are quite reasonable about this...because they have to be in order to do business with mathematicians.  The Proceedings of the AMS is published of course by the **A**merican **M**athematical **S**ociety.  The [current managing editor](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~ono/) of this journal [posts his preprints to the arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.01472). The linked-to preprint was submitted to the arxiv and for publication on the same day; a modified version was uploaded to the arxiv after the paper was accepted and before the paper was published.  So I think you have nothing to worry about here.

Comment: Thank you so much Pal;)I also thought that there would be no problem but you made me feel better and certain. Good night.

Comment: Small correction: it is possible to upload papers which **the authors** have formatted in the journal's style file.

Comment: Nice answer. I would add that the sherpa romeo database  (http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/index.php) has all the info about journal policies

Comment: @Federico: It's certainly possible, and I do not claim that it's not permissible, but I don't do it myself.  I actually never submit papers to a journal in the journal's style file...even when the online instructions say to do so.  I feel that there's no good reason for the journal to ask for this upfront, and as a referee when I (very rarely) see that the authors have done this, it (not so rationally, perhaps) feels a bit presumptuous to me.

Comment: For the Proceedings of the AMS, see the corresponding entry in SHERPA/RoMEO at http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/search.php?issn=0002-9939

Comment: UPDATE: since 2022, Proceedings of the AMS has a double-blind review model, which means authors should endeavor to keep their connection to the paper secret. Please read the submission guidelines carefully before uploading to arXiv if you plan to publish in Proceedings of the AMS: https://www.ams.org/news?news_id=6983

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in Pete Clark's answer, you can absolutely arXiv your paper before submission, after submission, after acceptance (in the post-referee, author formated version), or after publication in any AMS journal.

Most publishers have equally liberal policies with respect to arXiving papers, which is summarized at [SHERPA/RoMEO](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/index.php). However there are some pitfalls (which to the best of my knowledge have had no practical implication whatsoever) with some publishers.

Elsevier has an habit of mudding its policies, so it is safer to arXiv papers before submission, to retain the right to update it according the referee's requests.

Some publisher officially forbid the authors to publish the post-review version of a paper in repositories such as arXiv. This is the worst policy I know, as it implies forbidding to correct errors or inaccuracies in available preprints. Unfortunately, even some academic publishers such as Oxford University Press, engage in such nonsense. In practice, I did violate this clause of a copyright transfer agreement I signed, and nothing happened. Maybe they'll go after me know that I confessed.